# Did Structural directive like *ngIf affect the application or page performance?

Tags: angular

If I am using *ngIf in many places of my Angular 4+ components html, will it affect the performance of application or the particular page? If it affects please suggest a better way to over come the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice if the `DOM` elements aren’t visible, you should remove them from the `DOM` by using `*ngIf` instead of simply hiding elements with `CSS`. As the saying goes, the fastest code is code that is not run—and the fastest `DOM` is `DOM` that doesn’t exist.

Using a lot of `*ngIf` will help you to have less `DOM` so its good.

You can refer below article for angular best practices ,

https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/05/04/angular-2-best-practices-change-detector-performance/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it in simple components like paragraphs and all it will not affect the performance but if you are using them on components which are highly resource intensive then it may affect the performance of the app. Highly resource-intensive components means here are components that you create `<app-navbar></app-navbar>`.
[image]
For more information on structural directives visit

https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives